# Remove MongoDB documents that are more than 6 months old

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I’m using Mongoose to connect with my MongoDb cluster.

My site has a logging feature. I would like these logs to deleted once they are 6 months old. To do this, I have a file that runs every day to delete documents that are more than 6 months old.

However, the `deleteMany()` function does not provide me with context to run a function on each document, only that every document has a specific value.

Dates are stored as numbers (shown below)

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Sch = new mongoose.Schema( {
    id: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: true
    },
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'John'
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'Doe'
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: true
    },
    seven_shifts: {
        type: Object,
        default: {},
    },
    positouch: {
      type: Array,
      default: {}
    },
    departments: {
        type: Array,
        default: [],
        required: true
    },
    locations: {
        type: Array,
        default: [],
        required: true
    },
    tip_periods: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },
    w_4: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    employedSince: {
        type: Number
    },
    notes: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },
    last_login: {
        type: Number
    },
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model('User', Sch, 'users');
```

All I need is a way to check if the number in "date" is less than the one I provide in the function

Does anybody know of a way I can delete the matching documents in one query?

Thanks.

Comment: What query do you use now? Add that too

Comment: @Inder I don't have anything written yet I was just hoping to use `deleteMany` I wasn't sure how to do this at all since I can't use a function to test the documents

Comment: Add the schema for your logs model

Comment: You want to delete by checking `last_login`?

Comment: @Inder Yes if the time from now is greater than 6 months

Comment: But why have you set it to Number? Shouldn't it be Date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244523/discussion-between-thetechguy61705-and-inder).